# Angular and electron communication

Tags: angular, electron, angular7

I am trying to integrate my angular application with electron and want to bind and send message from electron to angular. My code is as follows:

```
App.module.ts:

import { NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxElectronModule   // Add it here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }


AppComponent.ts:

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) {}   // DI



}
```

My model class is as follows:

```
export class Model {
   firstName:String
   lastName:String
}
```

How can I send content in model class to from Angular to electron

It  can be a duplicate question but I am newbie to this so  need a detailed explanations to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did it using available IpcRenderer and IpcMain method provided by Electronserice